# Excel Conditional Format by Formula containing Cell(Address) in more than one cell

Tags: excel

I have a list of cell addresses (B1:B100) in one sheet, which refer to a range (A1:Z26, for example) on another sheet.

I have been trying to link these through conditional formatting (say, to light up red). By formula, I can have the following work...

=cell("address",a1)=B1  ; this makes the cell in the range refered to in B1 light up red.

But when I try to apply this to the whole list, as in =cell("address",a1)=B1:B100 it does not work...

Can anybody help me find a way forward here?

[the issue illustrated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZpF7.png)

Comment: Can you give a few more examples plz? Am I correct in guessing that you want a cell in A1:Z26 to light up if its address matches any addresses listed in B1:B100?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Specifically, I have the range which is like a chess board (A1:Z26) and a list (B1:100) which lists the position of pieces. So I want conditional formatting to trigger for each cell listed in B1:B100. I can have it work for one cell B1 but B1:B2 or larger and it does not compute.

Comment: If your list is in `Sheet2`, try with this formula: `=MATCH(CELL("address",A1),Sheet2!$B:$B,0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly modifying your original formula, you could try:

```
=MATCH(CELL("address",A1),Sheet2!$B:$B,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you select A1:Z26, clear any existing CF from it, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=MATCH(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4),another!$B$1:$B$100,0)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

References in the B column should be relative format.